# BitmapFactory decode an BMP image

Tags: android, bitmap

I am using [this code](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) from android developer blog for downloading a BMP file like [this one](http://wvnvms.wvnet.edu/vmswww/images/test32bfv4.bmp). BitmapFactory.decodeStream always returns null with skia returning false.

I've also tried using BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray with same result.
The framework [supports BMP files](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core), so what am i missing?

Thanks

EDIT: The code in the blog works for PNG and JPEG images.

Comment: What are the values of `inputStream` and `entity`?  (I found those in the sample you linked to).

Comment: Make sure that you have all required permissions defined in manifest file. Have you tried decoding local bitmap?

Comment: @Haphazard The inputStream and entity work fine. While debugging i tracked the number of bytes read by the decoder and it's stops at some a value for each BMP file.


@Audrius I haven't tried that. Will do that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, i found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/10a3821158f17be1?pli=1), you need to wrap the HttpEntity with a BufferedHttpEntity.

```
BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
```