# Android BinaryFactory.decodeStream always return null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmapfactory

I am trying to download image and decode it to bitmap using BitmapFactory, but decodeStream always return null. I've googled many similar questions, tried many examples, but didn't find solution.

Here is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void downloadButton(View v)
    {
        String imageUrl = "http://www.picgifs.com/bird-graphics/bird-graphics/elf-owl/bird-graphics-elf-owl-527150.bmp";
        new Thread(new ImageDownloader(imageUrl)).start();
    }

    public void showImageButton(View v)
    {
        Bitmap image = ImageHandler.getImage();
        if (image == null)
            Log.e("Error", "No image available");
        else {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        }
    }
}

class ImageHandler
{
    static protected List<Bitmap> imagesList;
    static public void addImage(Bitmap image)
    {
        imagesList.add(image);
    }
    static public Bitmap getImage()
    {
        if (!imagesList.isEmpty())
            return imagesList.get(0);
        else
            return null;
    }
}

class ImageDownloader implements Runnable
{
    public Bitmap bmpImage;
    private String urlString;
    public ImageDownloader(String urlString)
    {
        this.urlString = urlString;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(urlString);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            inputStream = (new BufferedHttpEntity(entity)).getContent();
            bmpImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            //bmpImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(urlString).openConnection().getInputStream());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("ImageDownloadError", e.toString());
            return;
        }
        if (bmpImage != null)
        {
            ImageHandler.addImage(bmpImage);
            Log.i("Info", "Image download successfully");
        }
        else
            Log.e("Error", "Bitmap is null");
    }
}
```

p.s `showImageButton` throws `IllegalStateException`, but I was already sick of it.

Comment: i'm not sure you may decode a `.bmp` file... EDIT: maybe an answer to this question may help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886583/bitmapfactory-decode-an-bmp-image?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @cyborg86pl i tried download jpg and png and gоt the same result.

Comment: @cyborg86pl tried method from the link, still error, but i get  "SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null" instead of "decoder->decode returned false"

Comment: can you update your code, please?

Comment: Sure. I've been thinking, maybe it because of my jdk version? I use jdk8.

Comment: If bmpImage stays null then which exception do you catch? What is the stacktrace? Do you have internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: @greenapps "new URL" requires try statement, stacktrace -http://pastebin.com/mtc0VWEP, Yes, i have `INTERNET` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` premissions.

Comment: Well there are several exceptions listed in your pastebin. Did you see them?

Comment: @greenapps yeah, but i dont quite understand what does they mean, im just one day in java (and android) development, also that exceptions not always arrear

Comment: Ok. I did not try your code. But for downloading a file there are many, many, many examples here on stackoverflow. So just google around a bit and try other solutions.

Comment: i've tried probably all examples

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is  that once you've used an InputStream from a HttpUrlConnection, you can't rewind and use the same InputStream again. Therefore you have to create a new InputStream for the actual sampling of the image. Otherwise we have to abort the http request.

Only once we can use inputstream for httprequest, if you are trying to download another image,then it will throw an error as "InputStream already created" like this. so we need to abort the httprequest once downloaded using httpRequest.abort();

Use this:

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(path) );
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufHttpEntity.getContent());
httpRequest.abort();
```

Comment: still the same, returned null :( I really dont get why it happens.

Comment: can you please share your layout file(activity_main) code.

Comment: i think u need to add onClickListner on downloadButton.share ur xml code so that i can tell you specific reason.

Answer (score 0):

as per my view two Reasons are there

1. class ImageHandler is not able to get the image
2. android is giving problem to take gif image from source.

I am uploading a working code hope this will solve Your Problem.

MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private String url = "http://www.9ori.com/store/media/images/8ab579a656.jpg";
    private Bitmap bitmap = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                        "", "Loading..");
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        bitmap = downloadBitmap(url);
                        messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    }
                }.start();

            }
        });
    }

    private Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };

    private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
        // Initialize the default HTTP client object
        final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        //forming a HttoGet request
        final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
        try {

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

            //check 200 OK for success
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode +
                        " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
                return null;
            }

            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream is = null;
                try {
                    // getting contents from the stream
                    is = entity.getContent();

                    // decoding stream data back into image Bitmap
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                    return bitmap;
                } finally {
                    if (is != null) {
                        is.close();
                    }
                    entity.consumeContent();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getRequest.abort();
            Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "Error "+ e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:text="Download Image" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and also don't forget to give INTERNET Permission in Manifest.xml file